# Spot metering with spectrometer?

Tags: metering, spot-metering, spectrometer

Most spectrometers only have incident light sensors. Is there any kind of accessory that will allow light from a particular place to be fed to the spectrometer?

In other words, if I wanted to use a spectrometer as a spot meter, how could it be done?

Comment: Does this comply with the recommended operation of the device? You could compromise any reliability by modifying the device or its recommended operation.

Answer (score 1):

The Incident method of light measurement gets its name from Latin “falling upon”. Most incident light meters have a light receptor that views the world with an angle of acceptance of 180°. It would be possible to change this angle of view by simply restricting the angle of view with simple tube, blackened on the inside. This could be further refined by installing a lens that to restrict the angle of view and concentrate this view to spot of light projected on the surface of the sensor. Photographic hand-held pot meters utilize a miniature telescope affixed ahead of the sensor.

Answer (score 1):

Devices called "Light Pipes" are often used to get luminary output to (easy) and into (harder) various places.

These will influence the response of the spectrometer due to their materials or configuration. You'll have to find what influence your chosen device has and how consistently it performs by experiment.

You have choices. There are fibres, fibre bundles, coherent fibre bundles, mirror chains, prisms, prism assemblies, air (or gas filled) interfaces, and several combinations of all of these.